# What happens behind the scenes when Chrome launches zoom.us as a stand alone app?

Tags: google-chrome, web-applications, client

When I click on a zoom.us invitation, which has the https protocol, Chrome asks me whether I would like to open zoom.us and then launches a stand-alone process.

I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597071/how-does-google-chrome-launch-desktop-apps) which gives some background but suggests using a custom protocol to trigger the launch.

In order to achieve similar behavior, what should I do?

Comment: Maybe a redirect to a custom protocol.I can't find it in the network log, but I don't have a lot of experience with front-end.

Answer (score 0):

So as my comment suggests, it does perform a behind the scene call to a custom protocol `zoommtg://` After it fetched some resources from the original URL